# Why is systemLayoutSizeFittingSize returning (0, 0) for UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

Here is the code snippet

```
    self.xyzIcon = [UIImage mobileImageNamed:@"icon_xyz"];
    self.xyzIconImageView = [UIImageView new];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.xyzIconImageView];

    [self.xyzIconImageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(weakSelf.contentView.mas_left);
        make.width.equalTo(@(weakSelf.xyzIcon.size.width));
        make.height.equalTo(@(weakSelf.xyzIcon.size.height));
    }];
```

In the view controller, which uses tableview

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (!self.prototypeCell) {
        self.prototypeCell = [UITableViewCell new];
    }

    [self.prototypeCell configure];

    CGFloat heightCalculated = [self.prototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height + 1.f;

    NSLog(@"Height calculated %f", heightCalculated);

    returns heightCalculated; 
}
```

This always returns 1.f. Please help and I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is that your constraints are not determinative of the height of the cell. You have not pinned the top of the image view or the bottom of the image view to its superview (the `contentView`). So the cell has nothing internal to keep it from collapsing all the way to zero, as it were, when you call `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`.

To put it another way: the way `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` works is by treating something's internal constraints as struts that give it a minimum (or maximum) size. You have no struts.

Comment: That made so much sense. But still it is not working :(. I added this :make.top.equalTo(@0);

Comment: Uh-huh. Did you read what I said? You must _pin_ the top _and_ the bottom of the image view _to the content view_. You didn't do that. I can't help you if you don't listen.

Comment: OK I had missed the bottom. Thank you.

Comment: When I add a bottom constraint it conflicts with another one so I solved it by making the bottom constraint with 999 priority

Comment: Thank you too! you answer helps a lot!